# How to get exit status of a command in zsh precmd function?

Tags: zsh

I am using add-zsh-hook precmd with a function so that I can add some contextual information around a command being run.

That said, it seems the invocation of the precmd function does not provide any args or any env variables to determine if the previous command was successful or not.  It would be nice to know so that I can take a different action on the result.

sample:

```
_after() {
  printf 'args:%s\n' "$*" # nothing
  printf 'After\n'
  # env #: nothing useful here
}

autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd _after
```

Comment: The `precmd` hook functions are executed before the prompt is built; the hook is not really related to the commands that came before. You may have better luck with the [`preexec` hook](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions).

Comment: Thanks, with preexec, I get the command the user wants to run along with the alias.  I also printed out env and there weren't any variables indicating the return status and _ (the last command run) was set to the directory where I am importing scripts, so this appears to be run just before the command is executed as the name implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of the last command is accessible within a `precmd` hook via the usual `$?` and `$status`. Keep in mind that only the very first command in the hook can retrieve it. It's not uncommon to save `$?` in a dedicated parameter on the first line of a `precmd` hook.

```bash
my-precmd-hook() {
  local -i code=$?
  printf 'exit code of the previous command: %d\n' code
}

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my-precmd-hook
```

The documentation isn't great on this point but it does exist.

> **Hook Functions**
>
> For the functions below, it is possible to define an array that has the same name as the function with `_functions` appended. Any element in such an array is taken as the name of a function to execute; it is executed in the same context and with the same arguments and same initial value of `$?` as the basic function.
>
> **`precmd`** Executed before each prompt.

Thus, all functions from the `precmd_functions` array are executed with the same `$?` as the main `precmd` hook. The documentation does not explicitly say that `$?` is the status code of the last command within the main `precmd` hook but it is implied. If `$?` were not the status of the last command, *that* would have to be documented.

Further we find:

> The shell function `add-zsh-hook` provides a simple way of adding or removing functions from the array.

This implies that `precmd` hooks installed with `add-zsh-hook` are also executed with the same `$?` as the main `precmd` hook.

Comment: Good call, I tested this and it works.